# Could we bring the elections site into this year?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, dates, election-page

On the [Stack Exchange Elections Page](http://elections.stackexchange.com/), the title is:

> Stack Exchange 2011 Election Nominee Information

Could that be updated to

> Stack Exchange **2012** Election Nominee Information

Comment: Should we really ... you know ... *need* to do that in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The year has been removed from the title of the page - for the PEOPLE!